# Grails form error: Tag [null] is missing required attribute [name] or [field]

Tags: forms, grails, attributes

```
Tag [null] is missing required attribute [name] or [field].
```

What does this error mean and what should I be looking for?

I went through the Grails docs and I have a valid name and type (which are the only required attributes according to the docs) for each form element, and it still returns that error.  (I'd post my entire form, but it has some organization-sensitve stuff in it.)

Comment: That could come from a number of places and I think 2 things are going wrong. I expect that you have a bug in your code that is not supplying a field or name attribute somewhere and there is a bug in the core tagLib that is not filling in the value of attrs.tagName under some circumstance that you are triggering.  Look for uses of `form` or `field` tags that don't have a name. There are others that could be the culperate, but that is where I would start. If I had an app that demonstrated the problem it would be trivial to identify. Best of luck.

Comment: The stack should help tell you which tag is the culperate and if not, if you are setup to operate in a debugger, setting a breakpoint at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/85518563de683cd08a16829ad6698671b217bc2b/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L293 should help.

Comment: which line would I be looking for in the stack?   2014-08-04 15:23:04,293 [http-bio-8099-exec-5] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsWrappedRuntimeException: Tag [null] is missing required attribute [name] or [field]

Comment: You are looking back through the stack until you get to a frame that corresponds to a particular tag implementation.

Comment: I'm working through the form piece-by-piece to see which one fails first.

Comment: I found it.  It was in an attachment type="file" field that I had two types and no name.

Comment: Excellent.  Which tag were you invoking?

Comment: it was in something like this.  I have repeating name attributes.  My brain was definitely playing tricks on me!  I looked the whole form up-and-down several times and missed it.  I had to break it down and put it back together piece-by-piece... <div class="form-group">
 <label id="attachment-label" class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="attachment">Add Attachment</label>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <g:field type="file" from="" class="form-control" name="attachment" required="" aria-labelledby="attachment-label"/>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: That tag invocation does have a `name` attribute though.  Is that the code which leads to the error?  I am trying to identify the problematic scenario so we can fix the error message. "Tag [null]" should be fixed to be "Tag [name of the tag here]".

Comment: yeah I'm not sure where the Tag[null] came from.   I think what I had originally was something like <div class="form-group">
 <label id="attachment-label" class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="attachment">Add Attachment</label>
 <div class="col-sm-5">
  <g:field type="file" from="" class="form-control" name="" required="" aria-labelledby="attachment-label"/>
 </div>
</div> -- I never had an null tag name (at least that I'm aware of...)

Comment: I know you didn't have a null tag name.  That null comes from a code path in Grails itself (not your code) which is supposed to populate the name.  If I knew what tag you were invoking to cause that problem, I could fix it.  If the tag you show there is causing the problem, that is a different bug because that tag does have a `name` attribute. By the time https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/85518563de683cd08a16829ad6698671b217bc2b/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L293 executes, `attrs.tagName` is supposed to have a value.

Comment: I think I see.  The empty string value for the name attribute might be the issue.  I will check that.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think I found the problem and fixed it.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/78c9c48dc465bd730ea2f0fb995186fc42d5387b.  Thanks again for the feedback.